# Relational Database column type performance

Tags: mysql, sql

Personally, I am pro maintainability. So a lot of my system design decisions is based on that.

## Design: A

For example, I've always designed my database as such:-
*`*` Denotes indexed column*

```
|id*|file_storage_type*|file_key|
|1  |gcs               |...     |
|2  |s3                |...     |
|3  |oss               |...     |
|4  |gdrive            |...     |
|5  |dropbox           |...     |
```

I still have value mapping in my code e.g.:

```
class FileStorageTypes
{
    public static AMAZON_S3 = "s3";
    public static GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE = "gcs";
    public static ALI_CLOUD_OSS = "oss";
    public static DROP_BOX = "dropbox";
    public static GOOGLE_DRIVE = "gdrive";
}
```

And I use them as such :

```
if(resource.fileStorageType == FileStorageTypes.AMAZON_S3)
```

## Design: B

What I saw, a lot of my peers do this:-
*`*` Denotes indexed column*

```
|id*|file_storage_type*|file_key|
|1  |2                 |...     |
|2  |1                 |...     |
|3  |3                 |...     |
|4  |5                 |...     |
|5  |4                 |...     |
```

And the value mapping as such:

```
class FileStorageTypes
{
    public static AMAZON_S3 = 1;
    public static GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE = 2;
    public static ALI_CLOUD_OSS = 3;
    public static DROP_BOX = 4;
    public static GOOGLE_DRIVE = 5;
}
```

Usage in the code is the same obviously.

## My Thoughts

**Maintainablity**
I like Design: A because its easier for developers to understand the value without the need to refer to the mapping.

**Size**
Don't care about size unless it greatly affects performance.

**Performance**
This is something I'm not sure of and hence this post.
I'm sure it negatively affect performance albeit at a negligible level which is fine.

I do have plans to refactor the column to `tinyint` **IF** the performance is very bad but so far with 500k rows, we are not facing any issues.

My question is, at what point will `Design: A` affect the performance beyond negligible?

Comment: You may use a junction table to relate the integer ordinal values to their string representations directly in your MySQL database.

Comment: As I understand this, the table is the file storage type table and each row gets a name  (design A) or number (design B). I think your design A is superior. You create thus a readable key you can use in your app. Why would you make it unreadable on purpose (design B)? You say that your concern is performance. You can happily neglect this. That the DBMS has to read a few bytes more is something that you will probably not notice. You can of course try this and measure how long the access takes. I suppose that in a loop of, say, 10000 queries you may see a difference of a second or two.

Comment: As long as you have short, readable, codes like "s3", use them; `ids` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. The reason why I ask is because I saw other senior developers using "Design: B" which I hated because it is so inconvenient to always have to refer to a mapping file. 

I was wondering if there are any big advantages to using "Design: B" and turns out there isn't. 

I do hope more people give a thought to other developers who had to maintain their code.